# Grouping rows so a column sums to no more than 10 per group

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table that looks like:

```
col1
------
2
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

with values sorted in ascending order.

I want to assign each row to groups with labels 0,1,...,n so that each group has a total of no more than 10. So in the above example it would look like this:

```
col1 |label
------------
2   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   3
```

I tried using this:

```
floor(sum(col1) OVER (partition by  ORDER BY col1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) /10))
```

But this doesn't work correctly because it is performing the operations
as:

```
floor(2/10) = 0
floor([2+2]/10) = 0
floor([2+2+3]/10) = 0
floor([2+2+3+4]/10) = 1
floor([2+2+3+4+5]/10 = 1
floor([2+2+3+4+5+6]/10 = 2
floor([2+2+3+4+5+6+7]/10) = 2
```

It's all coincidentally correct until the last calculation, because even though

```
[2+2+3+4+5+6+7] / 10 = 2.9
```

and

```
floor(2.9) = 2
```

what it should do is realise 6+7 is > 10 so the 5th row with value 7 needs be in its own group so iterate the group number + 1 and allocate this row into a new group.

What I really want it to do is when it encounters a sum > 10 then set group number = group number + 1, allocate the CURRENT ROW into this new group, and then finally set the new start row to be the CURRENT ROW.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Solving this problem requires scanning the table, row-by-row.  In SQL, this would be through a recursive CTE (or hierarchical query).  Hive supports neither of these.

The issue is that each time a group is defined, the difference between 10 and the sum is "forgotten".  That is, when you are further down in the list, what happens earlier on is not a simple accumulation of the available data.  You need to know how it was split into groups.

A related problem *is* solvable.  The related problem would assign all rows to groups of size 10, splitting rows between two groups.  Then you would know what group a later row is in based only on the cumulative sum of the previous rows.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'd be interested in hearing more about this idea as the only other option I have at this point is exporting to R which I want to avoid if at all possible.